# The number of integer solutions with restriction

Tags: combinatorics, generating-functions

How many integer solutions are there to $$\begin{aligned}
x_{1}+x_{2}+x_{3}=n
\end{aligned}$$ where $x_{1}\ge 0$ and is even, $x_{2}\ge 0$ , and $0\le x_{3}\le 2$  .

I don't think this problem can be easily solved by inclusion-exclusion, so I tried to use generating function. By the restriction, the generating function should be $$\begin{aligned}
&(1+x^2+x^4+\cdots )(1+x+x^2+x^3+\cdots )(1+x+x^2) \\ =& \frac{ 1}{1-x^2} \cdot \frac{ 1}{1-x} \cdot \frac{ 1-x^3}{1-x}
\end{aligned}$$ Then I want to expand this so I can determine the coefficient in front of $x^n$, which is the number of integer solutions. However, I got stuck here. Any help or other method to approach this? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You got the generating function
$$
f(x)=\frac{ 1}{1-x^2} \cdot \frac{ 1}{1-x} \cdot \frac{ 1-x^3}{1-x}=\frac{x^2+x+1}{(x-1)^2(x+1)}.
$$
From here the standard step is to use [partial fractions decomposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_fraction_decomposition). This way you would find
$$
f(x)=\frac{1}{4}\frac{1}{1+x}+\frac{3}{2}\frac{1}{(1-x)^2}-\frac{3}{4}\frac{1}{1-x}.
$$
Then we expand the individual summands using mainly geometric series sum and $\frac{1}{(1-x)^2}=\frac{d}{dx}(\frac{1}{1-x})$, hence we have
$$
f(x)=\frac{1}{4}\sum_{n \geq 0} (-x)^n+\frac{3}{2}\sum_{n \geq 0} nx^{n-1}-\frac{3}{4}\sum_{n \geq 0} x^n.
$$
Removing the term for $n=0$ for the middle sum and shifting the index we therefore arrive to
$$
f(x)=\sum_{n \geq 0} \left[\frac{1}{4}(-1)^n+\frac{3}{2}(n+1)-\frac{3}{4}\right]x^n.
$$
So the resulting formula is after some clean up
$$
\frac{(-1)^n+6n+3}{4}.
$$
I let you fill in the details which are mostly just algebraic manipulations (you can find very similar questions on the topic on this site as well, for example [Using partial fractions to find explicit formulae for coefficients?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/425862)).

Answer (score 1):

Case.(1) $n=2k$ is even:

If $x_3=0$, then it is $x_1+x_2=n$, so $x_1$ can take $0,2,4,...,2k$.

If $x_3=1$, then it is $x_1+x_2=n-1$, so $x_1$ can take $0,2,4,...,2k-2$.

If $x_3=2$, then it is $x_1+x_2=n-2$, so $x_1$ can take $0,2,4,...,2k-2$.

So totally, $k+1+k+k=3k+1=\frac{3n}{2}+1$

Case.(2) $n=2k-1$ is odd:

If $x_3=0$, then it is $x_1+x_2=n$, so $x_1$ can take $0,2,4,...,2k-2$.

If $x_3=1$, then it is $x_1+x_2=n-1$, so $x_1$ can take $0,2,4,...,2k-2$.

If $x_3=2$, then it is $x_1+x_2=n-2$, so $x_1$ can take $0,2,4,...,2k-4$.

So totally, $k+k+k-1=3k-1=\frac{3(n+1)}{2}-1$

Comment: thank you, I have edited.

Answer (score 1):

Continuing from your generating function

$$ f(x) = (1+x^2+x^4+\cdots) (1+x+x^2+\cdots) (1+x+x^2) $$

$$ f(x) = \left(\sum_{i=0}^\infty x^{2i} \right) \left(\sum_{j=0}^\infty x^j \right) (1+x+x^2) $$

When multiplying the first two terms, to find the coefficient of $x^k$ which is a sum of $x^{2i} x^j = x^k$ terms, we need the number of solutions to $2i+j=k, i \geq 0, j \geq 0$. Any solution to $0 \leq 2i \leq k$ gives a solution with $j=k-2i$. The count is $\left\lfloor \frac{k}{2} \right\rfloor + 1$.

$$ f(x) = \left(\sum_{k=0}^\infty \left(\left\lfloor \frac{k}{2} \right\rfloor +1\right) x^k \right) (1+x+x^2) $$

That is,
$$ f(x) = (1+x+2x^2+2x^3+3x^4+3x^5+4x^6 +\cdots) (1+x+x^2) $$

Now multiplying in the $(1+x+x^2)$ gives

$$ f(x) = 1+2x+\sum_{n=2}^\infty \left(\left\lfloor \frac{n}{2}\right\rfloor+1 + \left\lfloor \frac{n-1}{2}\right\rfloor +1 + \left\lfloor \frac{n-2}{2} \right\rfloor + 1\right) x^n $$

Also for any integer $n$, $\left\lfloor \frac{n-1}{2} \right\rfloor + \left\lfloor \frac{n-2}{2} \right\rfloor = n-2$, so

$$ f(x) = 1 + 2x + \sum_{n=2}^\infty \left(n + \left\lfloor \frac{n}{2} \right\rfloor + 1\right) x^n $$

Since the first two terms do match the general expression,

$$ f(x) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \left(n+\left\lfloor \frac{n}{2} \right\rfloor +1\right) x^n $$
$$ f(x) = 1+2x+4x^2+5x^3+7x^4+8x^5+10x^6+\cdots $$

The answer is then $n + \left\lfloor \frac{n}{2} \right\rfloor +1$. In other words, $\frac{3n}{2}+1$ if $n$ is even, or $\frac{3n+1}{2}$ if $n$ is odd.